# Generate a sequence of N natural numbers

Tags: elixir

In Ruby it is possible to do so using a splat

```
[*1..5]
# => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

How can this be done in Elixir?

I know that I could probably use `reduce` but maybe there is an easier way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Elixir has [Range](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/master/elixir/Range.html)s just like Ruby. They implement the [`Enumerable` protocol](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/master/elixir/Enumerable.html), so you don't need to convert them to lists in most cases. Ranges will usually behave the same way as lists:

```
iex> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] |> Enum.map(fn x -> x*x end)
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25]

iex> 1..5 |> Enum.map(fn x -> x*x end)
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
```

However, if you really need a list for some reason, you can do the conversion via [`Enum.to_list`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/master/elixir/Enum.html#to_list/1):

```
iex> 1..5 |> Enum.to_list
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```